# parse query string where value has "&"

Tags: python, regex, parsing, query-string

I am dealing with a third party socket API where I am getting a string response and converting it to JSON.

**example:**

`id=1000&name=Foo Bar`

I have tried `split('&')` and `parse_qsl` in order to get the results (as key, value). The issue is that for some records the value contains `&`

***example***

`id=1000&name=Foo Bar & Bros`

so the `& Bros` will be considered as empty value. Any idea of how to parse it as part of name key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.  The problem is that the string with the "Foo Bar & Bros" value is not a valid query string; spaces and the (textual) ampersand would need to be encoded.

But, presuming that 1) the "third party socket API" you mention is providing them to you in this broken form, and 2) the textual ampersands always have a space around them, you could do it like this:

```
def handle_ampersand_values(pseudo_querystring):
    ENCODED_TEXTUAL_AMPERSAND = " AMPERSAND "
    RAW_TEXTUAL_AMPERSAND = " & "
    encoded_ampersands = pseudo_querystring.replace(RAW_TEXTUAL_AMPERSAND, ENCODED_TEXTUAL_AMPERSAND)
    kv_segments = encoded_ampersands.split("&")
    kv_pairs = [segment.split("=") for segment in kv_segments]
    return {k: v.replace(ENCODED_TEXTUAL_AMPERSAND, RAW_TEXTUAL_AMPERSAND) for k, v in kv_pairs}

print(handle_ampersand_values("id=1000&name=Foo Bar & Bros"))
{'id': '1000', 'name': 'Foo Bar & Bros'}
```